# How to get last login details for a user from Azure Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, azure, rest, azure-databricks, azure-cli

I have admin access to Azure Databricks and we have a requirement where we need to get the last login time/timestamp of all users across a workspace on Azure Databricks.

I have used the Databricks API reference https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/users/get and get the response with **"active": true**  which says whether the user is active or not. But I want other login related information like when a particular user last logged in.

So is there any other API endpoint that I can use to get those additional login details?

Comment: No it doesn't appear this is available in the API.  If you have unity enabled you can query the system tables.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs

Comment: @Bee_Riii Yes I saw the link but could you please let me know how to have unity enabled because I ran the command from the article: https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/how-to-find-out-the-users-who-accessed-databricks-and-from-which/td-p/33320 and I get an error saying [UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the documentation below on how to enable Unity Catalog:

[Enable a workspace for Unity Catalog - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/enable-workspaces#--enable-your-workspace-for-unity-catalog)

After enabling it, you need to obtain **USE** and **SELECT** permissions on the required schemas from a metastore admin or another privileged user. Learn more about this here: [Grant access to system tables](https://docs.databricks.com/en/administration-guide/system-tables/index.html#grant-access-to-system-tables).

To enable Unity Catalog, you must have administrator permission. Therefore, you should contact your Databricks account administrator to enable UC and reach out to system tables or metastore admins to execute your command.

Typically, you will not have those permissions, so you will need to get details through them.
Enable a workspace for Unity Catalog - Azure Databricks
Learn how to enable an Azure Databricks workspace for Unity Catalog by assigning a Unity Catalog metastore.